# JQuery custom function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to make a portfolio element on my website but the jquery isn't working. My guess it has something to do with the changePortfolio() but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
$('.projects a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e){

        changePortfolio(title, text, src, animation){
                $(".description-head").html(title);
                $(".description-text").html(text);
                $('.preview').attr('src',src);
                $('.preview').animateCss(animation);
        }

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        switch(href){
            case "#project-portfolio":
                changePortfolio("PORTFOLIO", "This is the portfolio", "img/portfolio.jpg", "slideInLeft");
                break;
        }
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: `function changePortfolio()`? Also, what about extracting it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all when you click on .projects a[href^="#"] is the jquery code executed? if not maybe is an error whith this:`$('.projects a[href^="#"]')` 
also you forgot to declare changePortfolio as a function and to close your pharentesis. try this

```
    $(document).on('click','.projects a[href^="#"]', function (e){

        function changePortfolio(title, text, src, animation){
                $(".description-head").html(title);
                $(".description-text").html(text);
                $('.preview').attr('src',src);
                $('.preview').animateCss(animation);
        }

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        switch(href){
            case "#project-portfolio":
                changePortfolio("PORTFOLIO", "This is the portfolio", "img/portfolio.jpg", "slideInLeft");
                break;
        }
});
```